# C++ Using a Recursive Call

Tags: c++, recursion

A financial services company guarantees a 1% monthly compounded return on your investment.  You want to see how long it takes to reach a total of $1,000,000 (million dollars) in investment plus return.  Write a program that allows the user to enter a continuous monthly investment (Example - $500 every month) or ($1,000 every month).  The program should call a recursive method that returns and displays the total months needed to reach the $1,000,000 goal.

Here is what I have so far, the program isn't displaying anything. Thanks!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Function prototypes. 
int financeRecursion(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int investment = 0;
    int month = 0;
    int totalMonths = 0;

    cout << "Enter the amount of money you want to invest.\n\n";
    cin  >> investment;

    totalMonths = financeRecursion(investment, month, investment); // Function call. 
    if (totalMonths > 0)
        cout << totalMonths;
    else
        return 0;
} // End of main.

// Function definitions. 
int financeRecursion(int money, int months, int money2)
{
    if (money <= 0)
        {return 0;} // Base case. 
    if (money2 <= 1000000)
        {return financeRecursion(money, 
                                 months + 1, 
                                 money2 + money2 * 1.01);} // Recursive call. 

} // End of function.
```

Comment: Look at your base case.  The function will only terminate when `money <= 0`.  When do you ever change the value of `money`?

Comment: Set a smaller goal and learn how to use a debugger to step through the code line by line..

Comment: So what should the base case be?

Comment: *the program isn't displaying anything.*  -- There is only one place in your code where you print output (other than the prompt), and that is `if (totalMonths > 0)`.  So you couldn't debug starting from there?

Comment: Please let me know the contact details of this company and I will fix the code for you. 1% of guaranteed monthly interest is too good of an opportunity to pass.

Comment: I have never been taught to use the debugger.

Comment: @ashley_0213 I get some output here: http://ideone.com/v8sweR

Comment: @ashley_0213 *I have never been taught to use the debugger* -- Now is a good time to learn.

Comment: @ashley_0213 _"I have never been taught to use the debugger."_ Teach yourself then, it's an essential skill for programming.

Comment: @ashley_0213 The other error is that you're doing this: `money2 + money2 * 1.01` and all of your variables are integers.   That fractional part of the value is going to be truncated.

Comment: This is what I have now...

Comment: 'int main()
{
 double investment = 0;
 int time = 0;
 
 cout << "Enter the amount of money you want to invest.\n\n";
 cin >> investment;

 financeRecursion(investment, time, investment); // Function call. 
 return 0;
} // End of main. 
// Function definitions. 
void financeRecursion(double money, int months, double money2)
{
 if (money <= 0)
 {
  return;
 } // Base case. 
 if (money2 <= 1000000)
 {
  return financeRecursion(money, months + 1, (money + money2) *1.01);
 } // Recursive call. 

 cout << "\n\n" << months << "\n\n";
} // End of function.'

Comment: As you can see, a comment doesn't format your code.  You should edit this into the original question -- which, by the way, is explained in the intro materials you should complete before posting.

Comment: _"Here is what I have so far, the program isn't displaying anything. Thanks!"_ Really? "It doesn't work or something. I don't know why; that's your job. Just fix it. I'll be back in an hour."

Answer (score 0):

Let's see whether we can summarize and put this issue to rest:

1. You get no output because your only print statement doesn't display anything.
2. There's nothing to display because when you hit $1M, your recursion routine simply falls through without display: the only value it *can* return is the 0 for an invalid investment.
3. Move from integers to floats.  Otherwise, the interest on fractions of $100 gets lost, and you get the wrong answer.  For instance, an investment of less than $100 will make an infinite loop.
4. I think you have a computation error in your recursive call: the added investment is **money**, not **money2**.  I think this expression should be

   ```
   money + money2 * 1.01
   ```
5. **money <= 0** is an error case, not a base case.  This should be in the main program.  The termination case for your recursion is when the investment value hits a megabuck.  Alternately, you could start at $1M and divide by 1.01 until you reach or go under the investment value.
6. Learn basic debugging.  First of all, put in extra print statements.  You have a sick program; ask where it hurts.  For instance, insert a print statement at the top of **financeRecursion** that prints the input arguments.  This will trace both data flow and execution flow -- to some degree.
7. Use more descriptive variable names.  (money, months, money2) are not obvious; try a set more like (principal, num_period, invest_value).  This may be why you got the wrong principal addition in your **money2** recursion.